# Android download behavior

Tags: android, download

Is there a guideline for a download task on an Android? Let's say, user initiates an app download on an Android (not from Apps app but from a 3d party app). What are the expected control on a "Downloading" window? I would assume [X] to quit the download. Is there an established guideline?

Comment: I would emulate the App Store's activity as closely as possible (which is pretty much what Amazon's app store does), make sure you have a notification showing the progress of the download unless it's something very short. Not sure why you'd need a download window; is this something so brief/important it should half the use of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically downloads on Android are handled with a notification, so the user can get on and do other things while the download progresses. Sometimes this uses a toast for notification when it's completed.

For reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

In the Play Store they also use a progress bar with the following UI:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb7eGx.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This is just contained inline, replacing the [Accept/Download] button after the user clicks it - there's no separate window needed. Incidentally, when the download is completed the user is presented with two options: [Open] and [Uninstall].